# Remove role in Hasura

Tags: graphql, hasura

I want to permanently delete a role in Hasura's permissions. For example here i would like to remove "service_admin" role

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options (in hasura 1.3)

## 1. On relation level

[image]

## 2. For all relations

[image]